# Xcode - [UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (7) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've just implemented the `AGPhotoBrowser` class into my Xcode project and I'm getting the error of:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (7) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
```

The code where the crash happens is here:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!self.currentWindow.hidden && !_changingOrientation) {
        [self.overlayView resetOverlayView];

        CGPoint targetContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

        UITableView *tv = (UITableView*)scrollView;
        NSIndexPath *indexPathOfTopRowAfterScrolling = [tv indexPathForRowAtPoint:targetContentOffset];

        [self setupPhotoForIndex:indexPathOfTopRowAfterScrolling.row];
    }
}
```

The crash seems to happen as soon as I exit the `ViewController` where this is implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error tells you that your table does not have any row at index 7. It means that your table view consists of 7 rows and maximum range of indexPath.row can be 6 (because row index of a UITableView starts from 0). Whenever you will call a row at index path beyond range of the table, it will throw an error.

Comment: I managed to fix it - thanks man! It was because the datasource delegate I was using was pulling number of items in the tableview from  an NSMutableArray, so I did:

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        assets = nil;
        ag = nil;
    }

:)

Answer (score 1):

Reload the `TableView` data before calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath()`.

```
[contentTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I neglected to set the tableview's Delegate and DataSource; so it seems that `nil` is also "out of bounds".

*Xcode:6.4, iOS:8.x*